# Flex: add days to date

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, date

I have two date components, Date_from and Date_to. if user select any date in "Date_from " then i want to add 6 days in the selected date and want to show that in second component "Date_to ".
my code

```
var Date2:Date = new Date() ;
var Date1:Date = pe_date_from.selectedDate;
Date2.setDate(Date1.date + 6);
pe_date_to.selectedDate = Date2;
```

it works fine for the first time but if user select 06/02/2012 it shows 12/02/2014 instead of 12/02/2012.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the from date for Date2

```
var Date2:Date = pe_date_from.selectedDate;
var Date1:Date = pe_date_from.selectedDate;
Date2.setDate(Date1.date + 6);
pe_date_to.selectedDate = Date2;
```

Comment: `var temp_date:Date = pe_date_from.selectedDate; 
    var day:Number = temp_date.getDate();
    var month:Number = temp_date.month;
    var year:Number = temp_date.fullYear;
    var new_date:Date = new Date(year, month, day + 6);  
    pe_date_to.selectedDate = new_date;`

Answer (score 0):

When adding dates, you should use the [Date().time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time) property.

For example:

```
function add(time:Number, toDate:Date = null):Date
{
    toDate ||= new Date();
    return new Date(toDate.time + time);
}
```

Where the parameter time, would be the number of milliseconds in a day times the number of days. There are 86400000 milliseconds in a day.

```
var yourNewToDate:Date = add(86400000 * 6, selectedFromDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as3commons framework http://www.as3commons.org/

```
DateUtils.addDays
```